# When using unwrap in BeautifulSoup the deleted tag is not thoroughly delelted

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

After using unwrap(), I used get_text(separator =  "\n") to get all the paragraph separately.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
string = """<p>paragraph1 paragraph1 <em>paragraph1</em> paragraph1</p>
        <p>paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2</p>"""    
string = BeautifulSoup(string,"lxml")
string.em.unwrap()
result = string.get_text(separator = "\n")
print(result)
```

I hope the result in 2 lines. The first line is paragraph1 and the second is paragraph2

Here is the actual result:

```
paragraph1 paragraph1
paragraph1
 paragraph1

paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph
```

Comment: Good job, you followed the template perfectly.

Comment: By the way, unwrapping a tag does not delete it. It just removes that node and replaces it with its contents in the DOM tree.

Comment: So is there any to fix my problem?

Comment: Yes, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs -

> ### [`Tag`.`unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap)
>
> `Tag.unwrap()` is the opposite of `wrap()`. It replaces a tag with
>   whatever’s inside that tag.

Basically, if you have a DOM tree that looks like this -

```
   soup
   / \
  B   C
 / \
D   E
```

And call `soup.B.unwrap()`, you should get something like this -

```
  soup
 / | \
D  E  C
```

Although I believe you're expecting something like this -

```
   soup
     \
      C
```

For this purpose, you could look at -

> ### [`PageElement`.`extract`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract)
>
> `PageElement.extract()` removes a tag or string from the tree. It
>   returns the tag or string that was extracted.

For your code, that would be -

```
string.em.extract()
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Extract will completely remove the contents too, so instead of having 4 "paragraph1" strings you will get only 3.

Answer (score 0):

Α kinda hacky (yet easy) way I found to solve this is to convert the "clean" soup into a string and then parse it again.

So, in your code

```
string.em.unwrap()

string_soup = str(string)

new_soup = BeautifulSoup(string_soup, 'lxml')


result = new_soup.get_text(separator = "\n")
print(result)
```

should give the desirable output